# Should I suggest a time when professor want to schedule an interview, or just say I always available ?

Tags: application, interview

I applied to a lab and a professor want to set up an interview (for the first time). In the reply email, he said that:

> "Please let me know when you are available. I am available on
>   Monday-Friday, after XX:XX."

I would say when I am available:

> "I would available everyday from XX to XX".

**Should I also suggest** a timeblock or not ?

> "I would suggest that we meet on Friday at XX:XX."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, pick a preferred time within the professor's constraints, and suggest it.  To be safe, propose a back-up (perhaps the following day) in case anything goes wrong.

Additional tip: Suppose the professor said he's available after 10 am.  Then to give him a little margin for error, I advise choosing a slightly later time, such as 10:30 am.

Comment: Yep.  The annoying thing here would be to endure 7 or 8 back-and-forth e-mails trying to nail down a time.  Those things drive me crazy.  By trying to knock yourself out to be accommodating, you can be wearing out the person you're trying to impress.

Comment: @B.Goddard - exactly.